# stackoverflow exception in my fibonacci series using .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am having a stackoverflow exception please help me fix this in my fibonacci series im using .net mvc

```
namespace taskmvc.Controllers
{
    public class fibonaccireccController : Controller
    {
       //this is my ActionResult
        public ActionResult fibonaccirecc() 
        {
            int number = 5;
            Fibonacci(0, 1, 1, number); 

            return View();
        }
        //this is my function
        public void Fibonacci (int a ,int b ,int c, int number) 
        {
            ViewData["factorial"] = a;//this is to send data to my view/
            if (c < number)
            {
              Fibonacci(b, a + b, c + 1, number);   
            }  

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line does the error occur on?

Comment: what should i return im new to this thing @fubu

Comment: i did it but still i am not having any series it should print something as in 'a'

Comment: what should i do ?

Comment: Is the problem an exception or rendering output?

Comment: You can always turn your recursive approach into a `while` loop.

Comment: now its not throwing an exception the problem is output now it should print  the series and i dont knw how to collect the numbers for viewdata plz explain it with the code .. sorry for troubling im totally new to these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change

```
 ViewData["factorial"] = a;
```

to

```
 ViewData["factorial"] += a.ToString();
```

to append the numbers instead of overwriting them each recursice call.

Comment: Error 1 Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'object' and 'int' C:\Users\harshitj\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\taskmvc\taskmvc\Controllers\fibonaccireccController.cs 24 13 taskmvc

Comment: add `ToString();`